# Import error in IPython notebook only with coopr.pyomo

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the [mathematical modelling package](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/coopr/wiki/Pyomo) `coopr.pyomo` successfully in both script files and interactively on the ipython console. However, if I try a simple `import coopr.pyomo` in an IPython notebook started by `ipython notebook`, I get the following error message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ff8219fceacd> in <module>()
----> 1 import coopr.pyomo

ImportError: No module named pyomo
```

Other imports (both buitlins and custom packages) work without trouble. Any ideas where to look for a cause?

*Environment: Python 2.7 (32 bit) on Windows 7, IPython 0.13.2, Coopr release 3.2.6148.*

**Edit: more diagnostics**

Indeed, coopr can be imported, yet has not `__file__` attribute. If I display `__dict__`, I get the correct path:

```
{'__name__': 'coopr', 
 'data': <module 'coopr.data' (built-in)>, 
 '__doc__': None, 
 '__path__': ['C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\coopr']}
```

If I browse in that directory, I find that all submodules (e.g. coopr.pyomo) are located in the `src` subdirectory. `data` seems to be a spurious directory with some test (test_baselines.py, test_perf.py) and example (diet1.py) files.

**Edit #2: it's getting closer (I think)**

The issue seems to be caused by the peculiar way how the windows installer of Coopr works. According to the [Installation Notes](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/coopr/CooprInstallGuide.html), Coopr sits encapsulated in its own virtual sandbox. This is underlined by its default installation directory suggestion **CH** := `C:/Packages/Coopr`. Last time, I ignored this sign and simply installed it to Python's `site-packages` folder. Now, for testing, I re-installed Coopr to this external directory. Coopr/Pyomo still can be successfully imported from within a (I)Python session, as `sys.path` is extended by all the subdirectories of the **CH**`/src/` directory.

However, these subdirectories look different from other packages I am used to. For example, src/coopr.pyomo only contains a setup.py, while `__init__.py` sits in **CH**`/src/coopr.pyomo/coopr/pyomo`. While IPython seems to be able to find the packages, IPython notebook -- although the search path is identical -- seems to get confused by the way the packages are organised.

Comment: How did you install the package? Your last paragraph describes it like it was copied from source straight into the `site-packages` directory, not by running `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Using the official [installer](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/coopr/downloader/download/file/52). I re-examined the procedure, see Edit #2 for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Evert for pointing me in the right direction. The issue was caused by my (careless) installing of Coopr into the `site-packages` directory of my Python installation. Note to self: *don't do that*. While IPython itself managed to find the packages, the search path of IPython's notebook got confused and treated the `coopr` directory like any other package folder.

After re-installing Coopr to its suggested location **outside my Python installation directory**, deleting the coopr directory from `site-packages`, followed by a reboot, everything works fine.

Comment: Glad it worked. I wnatead to have a quick look at the installation myself, but backed away at the registration and non-source installer. It does sound they use a convoluted setup and installation; not my favourite. Hope it keeps working for you ;-).

Comment: Indeed. I think pip-based installation could work in principle, but I refrain from setting up a build environment under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have to guess, but:

Try something like the following in the notebook:

```
import coopr
print coopr.__file__
```

It looks like you're picking up a different `coopr` module than the installed one, and the `__file__` attribute should tell you which one you're using. Perhaps there's a script called `coopr`; such a script would not contain a submodule `pyomo`.

Why would this only happen in the IPython notebook and not in the IPython console? My guess is that, if there is indeed a different `coopr` module, it lives in your home directory or somewhere else on the system that the IPython notebook uses as its "base". The IPython console base directory is where you started it, but the IPython notebook is probably decoupled and has a default base directory. I don't know how the notebook is run under Windows, so I can't tell you what that default is and where to look, but the above code could very well show you that.

Comment: Thanks for guessing! This situation is quite frustrating.. `coopr.__file__` does not exist, but I added the content of `coopr.__dict__` to my question plus some bits on my directory structure. Any more ideas?